# Possible to group views by date field larger than current date?

Tags: 6, views

I want to group my nodes into active and expired based on a date field. Currently I have the view set to group by this field but I don't want the active and expired groups to be broken down into specific dates such as 2 weeks, 3 days etc. I just want two groups, active and expired. How can I do this? An example of what I currently have http://www.glumbo.com/deals/footlocker.com-deals

Comment: You know what really sucks? Posting the same question on multiple places without waiting for a real answer!

Comment: What's wrong with that?

Comment: Because you could cause take time from two different people. At least from my perspective it's some kind of respect to the freetime of other people.

Comment: I didn't think of that. I'll be more considerate next time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used this module to accomplish this http://drupal.org/project/views_customfield. It allows you to define a new views field using custom php code